# Regular expression to extract text line by line

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

Is it possible to make a regex check line by line of the data? So if I have the text as:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="seedocs" tvg-logo="RT",RT
#http://odna.octoshape.net/f3f5m2v4/cds/ch5_320p/chunklist.m3u8
#http://odna.octoshape.net/f3f5m2v4/cds/ch5_720p/chunklist.m3u8
http://rt.ashttp14.visionip.tv/live/rt-global-live-HD/playlist.m3u8

#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="hsn" tvg-logo="hsn",HSN TV
rtsp://hsn.mpl.miisolutions.net:1935/hsn-live01/_definst_/mp4:420p500kB31
```

I want to remove all the text start from: #http:....

So that i have used the code as below:

To get the match data:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"((#EXTINF.*\r\n)(.*))+(http|https)://((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*\r\n)+([\\.|/]((\\w)*|([0-9]*)|([-|_])*))+" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

To Remove text start from #http...:

```
 NSRegularExpression *regexName = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"#.*$" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```

This will give the output as below in the log:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="seedocs" tvg-logo="RT",RT
```

which mean, i could not retrieve the value of:

```
http://rt.ashttp14.visionip.tv/live/rt-global-live-HD/playlist.m3u8
```

my output should be something like this:

```
#EXTINF:-1 tvg-name="seedocs" tvg-logo="RT",RT
http://rt.ashttp14.visionip.tv/live/rt-global-live-HD/playlist.m3u8
```

Please somebody help me to sortout this issue.

Comment: Why do you keep the first #EXTINF: but not the second? Perhaps the segments starting with #EXTINF: and ending with blank line are treated as separate blocks and only to be kept when containing http:// or you interested in the first http:// only?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to construct REs which match multiple lines, but doing so can be a challenge - both to you and the RE engine. You are usually better off matching single lines; for example you could match lines starting with `#http`, include the line terminator, and replace each such match with nothing.

However if you are doing line-by-line processing you might be even better off using `componentsSeparatedByString:` to first break your input into lines, and then processing each line - say by dropping those which start with `#http` (use `hasPrefix:`).

HTH

Answer (score 0):

Checkout the following code to do this: *I want to remove all the text start from: #http:....*

```
NSMutableString *finalString = string.mutableCopy;

[string enumerateLinesUsingBlock:^(NSString *line, BOOL *stop) {

    if ([line hasPrefix:@"#http"]) {
        [finalString replaceOccurrencesOfString:line withString:@"" options:NSCaseInsensitiveSearch range:NSMakeRange(0, finalString.length)];
    }
}];
```